# Wrong position number in a ListView

Tags: android, listview, position

I got this problem several times and even though I can't solve it

here's code from Adapter

```
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {


        if(convertView == null){
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.place_item_layout, parent, false);
            //HERE's my check
            (convertView.findViewById(R.id.divdePlaces)).setVisibility(View.GONE);
            if (place.isTOP()==false && position!=0) if (places.get(position-1).isTOP()==true) {
                //turn back on
                (convertView.findViewById(R.id.divdePlaces)).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);   
            }

.. etc..

}
return convertView;
}
```

So, this just turn on the divider line if conditions are met. I thought here the position should be the real number but it repeats again when ListView goes 1 screen up, even though the conditions for it are not met for sure.

How do I fix that?

[image]

[image]

Comment: What is this isTOP function you're calling?  Also, are you ever setting the view back to INVISIBLE in the case of scrolling?  Remember that views are reused and ALL visibilities, texts, etc of the UI must be completely set in each call to getView

Comment: @GabeSechan Is there a proper reference question for ListView recycling issues? I haven't found it so far and I was thinking about writing one, but since you've been here longer maybe you know of one already?

Comment: @matiash I have no idea, I don't pay much attention to reference questions.  I do know it's been answered before, by myself and others.  You can probably poke around a bit and find a good one.  Also, there was a great video from Google I/O a few years back on how ListViews work, it may be good to reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you scroll one page up, your views start to get recycled. Hence, convertView is already inflated and non-null.  Toggle the visibility of the divider outside of the if (convertView==null) block.

Something like this:

```
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
{


    if(convertView == null)
    {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.place_item_layout, parent, false);
    }

    int visibility = (place.isTOP()==false && position!=0) ? View.GONE : View.VISIBLE;
    convertView.findViewById(R.id.divdePlaces).setVisibility(visibility);

    return convertView;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

This problem is derived from view reuse in `ListView`. As you scroll down, the item views that exit from the top are reused (supplied as `convertView`) for the new items. Therefore, you need to make sure that you "undo customizations" if they no longer apply.

For example:

```
if (convertView == null)
{
     // create new view.
     convertView = inflater.inflate(...);
}

// OUTSIDE the previous if, and with both branches implemented.
if (check)
     (convertView.findViewById(R.id.divdePlaces)).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);   
else
     (convertView.findViewById(R.id.divdePlaces)).setVisibility(View.GONE);   

...
```